# XSLT Keep current contents of element then append with copy from another element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am looking to keep the current contents of an element and append to it with the contents from another element. The input XML would look like this:

```
<root>
    <existingContent>
        <elements id="x">
        <element>
            <elementA>John</elementA>
            <elementB>Doe</elementB>
        </element>
            <element>
                <elementA>Jane</elementA>
                <elementB>Doe</elementB>
            </element>
        </elements>
    </existingContent>
    <temp id="y">
        <element>
            <elementA>Joe</elementA>
            <elementB>Bloggs</elementB>
        </element>
    </temp>
</root>
```

The desired output like this:

```
<root>
    <existingContent>
        <elements id="x">
            <element>
                <elementA>John</elementA>
                <elementB>Doe</elementB>
            </element>
            <element>
                <elementA>Jane</elementA>
                <elementB>Doe</elementB>
            </element>
        </elements>
        <elements id="y">
            <element>
                <elementA>Joe</elementA>
                <elementB>Bloggs</elementB>
            </element>
        </elements>
    </existingContent>
</root>
```

Using the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/root/existingContent">
        <xsl:if test="./*">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:element name="elements">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="/root/temp/@id"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="/root/temp/node()"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/root/temp"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but getting this instead - a repeat of the parent element  when I want the content being copied as another child of :

```
<root>
   <existingContent>
      <elements id="x">
         <element>
            <elementA>John</elementA>
            <elementB>Doe</elementB>
         </element>
         <element>
            <elementA>Jane</elementA>
            <elementB>Doe</elementB>
         </element>
      </elements>
   </existingContent>
   <existingContent>
      <elements id="y">
         <element>
            <elementA>Joe</elementA>
            <elementB>Bloggs</elementB>
         </element>
      </elements>
   </existingContent>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use three templates (plus the identity transformation template, of course):

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::temp)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="existingContent">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node() | ../temp"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="temp">
    <elements>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </elements>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The base template, the identity transformation templates, copies everything recursively, level by level, and that way allows you to add templates for the nodes you want to change.

In your case, at the `root` level, you don't want to copy/process all child nodes but rather exclude the `temp` elements.

For the `existingContent`, you want to add the `temp` element(s) from the parent, so you need to subject to/select them for processing as content as well.

Finally, it looks like you don't want to copy `temp` elements but rather transform them to `elements` elements, so the template matching `temp` does that.

Comment: Thanks @martin-honnen that works for me. I've simplified my situation for the purposes of a clear question so could you please talk me through the logic to help me tidy up my actual results?

Comment: @bjh, see whether the edit helps.